# Backup large zfs disk on multiple hard drvies

Tags: backup, freenas

I have a FreeNas box with 8 1.5TB drives in raidz2 and I would like to backup on an other computer with 2TB drives not in raid.

Is there a way to automatically create a backup on multiple drives?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your total data size is less than the destination pool available capacity you can use `zfs send`.

Comment: I want to backup the zfs pool to the hard drives on an other computer. Not the hard drives to the zfs pool.